# Add unique id to "Reply-To"-header in swift mailer

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I want to setup a similar message structure as in github, where a user can either respond by email or logging into his account.

Github appears to have a unique-id in the reply-to field:

```
reply+i-39945717-887b26ec5b3de79d00dec7ef29ad308795b85685-6876349@reply.github.com
```

Is it possible to add a unique ID to the "Reply-to"-header with swift-mailer?

How would the mail server be able to work with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, why not? Setting `Reply-to` with SwiftMailer is quite easy:

```
<?php

$message = new \Swift_Message();
$message->setReplyTo(sprintf(
    'reply+%s@your-domain.com',
    uniqid()
));
```

The `uniquid()` call is just for example. In real-life code you'd persist the entity ID beforehand (e.g. when you save it), and retrieve it from your model object later.

However, you'll need to set up a mail checker that would receive your incoming mail, parse it and transform into CRUD operations on your database.

Comment: the last part is actually the thing I am stuck with. Isn't The reply-to field expecting an email address?

Comment: @apfz, well, isn't it a valid email address? The `+` sign is allowed there, and the mail should be received by the alias without the `+` sign and the suffix.

Comment: did not know it was allowed. thanks for this. However PHP is not fetching the value after (and including) the plus sign (it just trims it), but for that I will post another question.

Answer (score 4):

For `responding to` using email, you can use `In-Reply-To` alongside `Reply-To`.

For this purpose you can use this StackOverFlow answer: 
[Correct headers for replying and forwarding emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631563/correct-headers-for-replying-and-forwarding-emails/33633776#33633776)

In summary you need to track your message using its ID and its id is stored in `In-Reply-To` and this is the way you can set it:

```
$headers = $message->getHeaders();

$headers->addTextHeader('In-Reply-To', $previousEmail->getHeaders()->getMessageId());
```